# getJSON function conflicting with other simple functions

Tags: jquery, onclick, getjson

I am using getJSON to build a product list page - works fine - but in the same document I also have some simple on click functions which refuse to work. I'm assuming there's a conflict? Please help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
    var product_data = '';

    $.each(data, function(key, value){

  // Build product tile
    product_data += '<h3>'+value.name+'</h3>';
    });
    $('#plp-main').append(product_data);
  });

}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".element1" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".element2" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you also put data.json file also html which you tried

Comment: You can have multiple doc ready.  You're using event delegation.  Your get code doesn't appear to change .element1/.element2 (shouldn't matter as using even delegation).  There's no obvious in the code you've provided.  Could it be some other code elsewhere in your page/project?

Comment: aboce code will work fine if your "data.json" is fine.  if it is conflicting then there may be you are using jquery two time with differenet version

Answer (score 0):

It's a delegation issue following the append. Solved by binding the click event to the parent of the click element thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#parent" ).on( "click", ".element1", function() {
      $( ".element2" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

Thanks everyone for your interest!